# Nothing listening on Port 80, Windows Firewall OFF, .NET App using System.Net.HttpListener Running Fine

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, windows-firewall, http.sys

I've a Windows Service running in a VM that is not getting any HTTP traffic.  This is unexpected.

The app is a Windows Service running as "NTAUTHORITY\Local Service". It implements System.net.HttpListener to listen to HTTP traffic over port 80.  I start the Windows Service. It logs that it's up and has registered a Prefix "http:///api/".  I run `netstat -tan` and 0.0.0.0:80 does not show up as one of the Local Addresses that are LISTENING.

I've turned all 3 Firewalls, Private, Domain and Public, OFF and bounced my service.  No change. Rebooted VM, also no changed.

I do have a reserved URL via `"netsh http add urlacl url="<dns-name>:80/api" user="NTAUTHORITY\LocalService"`.

What am I missing?  Why would this not be working?

Comment: is it working inside the vm?

Comment: Not at the moment.

Comment: May i know , if you are able to access HTTP traffic from inside the VM ? if yes , then is the windows application the only one not able to access the internet ? if no , then can you check if you have port 80 opened in NSG rules for the VM and associated it to the Subnet which is tagged to the VM?